# inserting a row in a MS access database

Tags: java, database, ms-access, odbc

Geeks I don't know why this code doesn't work, it doesn't throw an exception but my access database is still the same and this row isn't added there I would be happy if you could help me, it only prints 1 as number f lines affected as I know but the data base is still the same.

```
    public void connect()
{
    try{
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String xx="jdbc:odbc:aaaaa";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(xx);  
        st=con.createStatement();
        int i=st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('aaaa','bbbbb',2014)"); 
        System.out.println(i);          
        st.close();

    } catch(Exception e)

        {System.out.print(e.toString());}           
    }
```

Comment: just in case, try adding con.setAutoCommit(true); before the executeUpdate()

Comment: also try to close the connection in the end

Comment: Thank you @Leo I closed the connection and everything works fine :) Visca Barca :D

Answer (score 1):

just in case, try adding con.setAutoCommit(true); before the executeUpdate() and close the connection in the end